# C# program and C++ DLL compiled for 32-bit system crash on 64-bit system

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll, 32bit-64bit

I have a C# application that makes use of a DLL as I need C++ to access some unmanaged functionalities of the user32 API (I cannot use PInvoke for that). I compile both the application and the DLL for x86 architectures, and everything works fine on Windows 7 32 bits. Now the problem is, on Windows 7 64 bits, the application crashes when I try to use the feature that relies on the DLL (but all the rest works fine).

I suspect that this is a 32/64 bits issue, so I tried re-compiling the DLL for x64 architectures, and now I can choose at runtime which DLL to load between the x86 and the x64. But it still crashes when I try to use the feature that relies on the DLL (which makes sense as I try to load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit program). I haven't tried yet to compile both the application and the DLL for x64. I suspect it would work, however it would require me to have two different installers, and I don't want to go there. Any clue?

Comment: If both are compiled for x86, it should work. Can you debug it on a 64bit system and give more details?

Comment: The 64-bit system I used for the test was the computer of a friend. To debug it, I will need to install Windows 7 64 bits in vmware or vbox, which I can do, but it's gonna take me some time to set it up.

Comment: Do you have the 32-bit CRT DLL's on the 64-bit system?

Comment: Yes, I do have the 32-bit CRT DLL's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When interoping with unmanaged code, you need to ensure your .Net app runs on the same subsystem (32-bit or 64-bit). As you've stated the DLL you're loading is for x86, force the .Net to build for only the x86 platform. This setting is found in your project's properties, on the build tab. The default is any CPU, change the setting to x86 to match your unmanaged DLL and you should be fine regardless if you run on a 64-bit or 32-bit OS.

Comment: I'll try that this weekend and I'll test on a 64-bit system. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. I thought that the executable was compiled as x86, but it was actually compiled as "Any CPU" as you suspected, and that was the only choice I was given in the list from the configuration panel. I had to go deep in the settings to find a choice between x86 and x64. So I selected x86 instead of Any CPU, and when testing on Windows 7 64-bit, the program worked! Well, the feature inside of the DLL isn't working properly, but at least the program starts and doesn't give any error message any more. So I am going to take this answer :) Thanks Nathan!