# DLL not working on x64 system

Tags: c++, .net, profiling, profiler

I just wrote a .NET profiler (a DLL which will be used by CLR). Actually, the DLL works on Windows XP with applications that are designed for `Any CPU` and `Win32` applications. However, on Windows 7 x64, it only works with applications designed for `x86` architectures. Where could be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE : is it possible to build a DLL for `Any CPU`?? if not, any alternatives?

Comment: Is your application **32 bit**?! If it's compiled as x86 it can't work in x64 world (on 64 bit OS applications Any CPU will run 64 bit)

Comment: @Adriano wrong, a 32 bit application can work in any world besides 16 and 8 bit :)

Comment: Tried : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4463418/1064610 ?

Comment: @VladL 32 bit applications CAN RUN on 64 bit systems but you CAN'T LOAD libraries within 64 bit applications. Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423

Comment: @ACB, Thanks for the quick answer but I managed to make my dll work with x86 apps and I'd like to make it work with applications compiled as x64 on x64 systems.

Comment: @HediNaily then if it's an unmanaged (or mixed) application you have to compile it for both versions (x86 and x64). A 32 bit DLL can't be loaded in a 64 application.

Comment: the problem is that you can't run 32 and 64 bit dlls in one process

Comment: @Adriano I'll try it (it's unmanaged)

Comment: Hope not setted for Itanium arch.

Comment: `error C1189: #error : "No target architecture"`
That's what I got when I tried to compile it as x64

Comment: Re: is that possible to build a DLL for `Any CPU`??

Comment: You have to compile it separately. See my implementation here https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme.Profiler (works for .NET 4.5 too ;p)

Comment: @leppie can your dll be compiled as x64 compatible?

Comment: @HediNaily: Sure, you just select the 'x64' solution configuration.

Comment: I concur with leppie you will need to have two profilers (one for each platform 32/64) see https://github.com/sawilde/opencover for an example

Comment: @leppie what does `inc time` mean in your profiler?

Comment: @HediNaily: Inclusive time IIRC.

Comment: @leppie and what does it represent? I couldn't find information about it

Comment: @HediNaily: That is the time for the method, including the time for child calls. As opposed to Exclusive time, that only measures the time spent in the method body.

Comment: @leppie have you an idea on profiling silverlight apps? In fact I'm writing a silverlight profiler (that supports GC, objects, Exceptions, Code transitions, methods monitoring). The profiler works fine with Internet explorer (because IE creates a separate process for each new tab) but with Chrome and Firefox there is only a single process for all tabs (when we want to profile 2 SL apps the output will be written to the same file).
Is there a way to separate the output?

Comment: @HediNaily: Dont know. If you launch the browser from the command line  with the env vars set, it should work. (quick response ;p)

Comment: Actually the profiler I'm writing doesn't need user intervention, the env vars are set globally and there is a config file that determines which apps to profile. In other words, the dll is loaded in all .NET processes and the eventMask is set according to the config file.

Comment: @HediNaily: Sorry, I did not read all of your message :) That is a tough one, but I guess you can output the threadid too in the output file. There might be processid around too, if the apps are multithreaded.

Comment: hi @leppie , it seems that my profiler has strange behaviour with x64 applications eg: when I use it with a VB .NET calculator, buttons get scrumbled and window and characters size are somehow strange. I tried to use your profiler and I got the same problem

Comment: @HediNaily: That seems expected as you are profiling all managed code including the Windows Message pump. Try filter out types starting with `System` to speed things up.

Comment: @leppie I'm already filtering. It works fine with x86 apps and that's what I don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution In [David Broman Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032252/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2006/11/13/wow64-and-your-profiler):

```
For x86 Machine 
 - Just run regsvr32 like you usually do.
For x64 or ia64 Machine    
 - If you want to be able to profile 64 bit apps, 
         run 64 bit regsvr32 against your 64 bit Profiler DLL
 - If you want to be able to profile 32 bit apps (WOW), 
         run 32 bit regsvr32 against your 32 bit Profiler DLL.
 - If you want to support both, do both!
```

In other words, if we want to profile all applications on a x64 machine we need to build 2 DLLs with the same GUID (CLSID), one for x86 applications and the other for x64 ones.

Comment: I told you that you could register them both

Answer (score 1):

Running a "Any CPU" app on a Windows 7 X64 machine will default to the 64-Bit (x64) CLR (common language runtime) unless you explicitly tell it to run in 32 bit (x86) mode.

You can force it to be loaded into the 32bit runtime by changing it's flags using a [commandline tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) available in the .Net SDK:

```
corflags.exe /32BIT+ myAssembly.exe
```

This will actually change it back to a x86 dll. Most likely, the reason it is working on your xp machine is because you do not have support for a 64 bit CLR on that machine, so it will allways run in 32bit x86 mode even though it's "Any CPU".

Also note that an "Any CPU" DLL will always default to the bitness of the host application loading it.

I assume you must be doing something in your profiler DLL that is not 64bit (x64) compatible. The question is what do you mean with "not working fine". Do you get an exception like "bad image format" or is the DLL called by another assembly that's compiled differently? What are the unexpected results?

Comment: As I understood, there's no way to work with only one dll for all apps. In this case, and having 2 dlls on a x64 machine how to set environment variables separately. i.e : I have a list of applications to profile and I know previously their compatibility, is there a way to force system to configure environment variables for an application before it runs (e.g making system execute a command line just before app execution)

Comment: Yes it should be possible, though I don't know how. I'm not into all OS options, but since it is possible to mark an app to run as administrator or in compatibility mode, I'm quite sure there is also a way to set app specific environment variables via the OS (probably in the registry). You could also bootstrap starting applications the way a virus scanner does, but I guess that's like shooting an ant with a bazooka. The place I'd personally look first is [.config files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx).

Comment: When you register the 32 and 64 COM assemblies they register in different parts of the registry (Wos6432Node for 32 bit) as such you just use the same environment variables and the runtime will use the correct registry areas - I use the same CLSID for both 32 and 64 bit COM objects

Comment: Well it seems to work for OpenCover (which is a .NET profiler) - have a look at the source.

Comment: @ShaunWilde if my previous comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243257/dll-not-working-on-x64-system?noredirect=1#comment21576156_15283811) was a question then I would have marked yours as an answer. Thanks

Comment: To that question not that I know of (though you can set them for a user or for a service (registry)). 

However it is possible for the profiler DLL to read a common environment variable (containing names of apps you want to process) and use them during Initialize, returning E_FAIL if it isn't an application you wish to profile.

Comment: @ShaunWilde Isn't it possible to register the same "Any CPU" dll twice, once under the 32 bit registry and once under the WOW64 stack? By the way, (off topic) thanks for OpenCover. Just yesterday I integrated it into our TeamCity build setup for profiling an ASP.Net application running in IIS express. Works great together with ReportGenerator!

Comment: No a profiler assembly has to be written in native code i.e. C++ and so your only options are 32 or 64 there is no such thing as AnyCPU in that scenario. Have a look at @leppie's profiler or the opencover code base. I'll refer to you to David Broman's blog on the whole subject http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/ and in particular to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2006/11/13/wow64-and-your-profiler.aspx